# Return data if the latest row is over 2 weeks old

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query who finds the latest row for the column s.work_id = 14681 and only displays one row which is fine.

My question is, how do I make sure, that the latest row, is for example over 2 weeks old? Every row in the work_status table has an date_added which is in datetime format. If the latest row is over 2 weeks old, it should be displayed.

My current query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM work_status s 
LEFT JOIN work w ON (s.work_id = w.id)
WHERE s.work_id = 14681
  AND w.investigation = '1'
  AND w.deleted = '0'
  AND w.investigation_winner = '0' 
  AND w.investigation_validated = '1' 
  AND w.work_denied = '0'
ORDER BY s.date_added DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Example Data:
[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeI4b.png)

Right now the query displays the first row, but as said, it should not return anything because the latest row is not over 2 weeks old.
[Query returns first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KMQw.png)

Comment: Do you want `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: You already get INNER JOIN result (since you have those right side table conditions in the WHERE clause.) Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: You should add a working Fiddle here, so that your problem is _reproducible_ (it currently is not).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause which checks that the date added is two weeks or older.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM work_status s 
LEFT JOIN work w
    ON s.work_id = w.id
WHERE s.work_id = 14681 AND
      w.investigation = '1' AND
      w.deleted = '0' AND
      w.investigation_winner = '0' AND
      w.investigation_validated = '1' AND
      w.work_denied = '0' AND
      s.date_added < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND
      (SELECT MAX(date_added) FROM work_status) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
ORDER BY s.date_added DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That does not meet the condition i set. The query you wrote will now return the row WHERE the id is 5583. But, it should not return anything as I said, the id 5628 is the latest row and the date is not over 2 weeks old. :)

Comment: @SandroOsmanerne I disagree.  If no records are more than 2 weeks old, my query should not return anything.

Comment: I added another condition to the `WHERE` clause which verifies that the most recent date added is also less than 2 weeks in order for any records to be returned.  Please try this.

Comment: Tested the code - now it does not return anything. But there is a bug:

I updated the date_time from 2017-01-04 10:50:01 to 2016-11-30 10:50:01 (which is over 2 weeks old) it still does not return anything, but it should.

Comment: Then there is a problem with the logic in _your_ query.  I can't do anything else here.  You should create a working SQL Fiddle in your question so that anyone can test against that.

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* do, building on @Tim's solution:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM work_status s 
LEFT JOIN work w
   ON s.work_id = w.id
WHERE s.work_id = 14681 AND
   w.investigation = '1' AND
   w.deleted = '0' AND
   w.investigation_winner = '0' AND
   w.investigation_validated = '1' AND
   w.work_denied = '0' AND
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.date_added, 120) <= DATEADD(WEEK, -2, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AND
  (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_added, 120)) FROM work_status) <= DATEADD(WEEK, -2, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
ORDER BY s.date_added DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I find, more often then not that timestamps gives inaccurate results, which is why I use date conversions.  the `DATEADD` function makes it easy to select the interval you're looking for.

I also added a `<=` as opposed to just `<` in case you require the extra day.

Hope this helps :)